# Получить тэги html с их содержимым (RegExp, java)

Tags: java, html, регулярные-выражения

Нужно вывести все тэги с их содержимым на экран.

Вот задание:

Вывести на консоль все теги, которые соответствуют заданному тегу
Каждый тег на новой строке, порядок должен соответствовать порядку следования в файле
Количество пробелов, \n, \r не влияют на результат
Файл не содержит тег CDATA, для всех открывающих тегов имеется отдельный закрывающий тег, одиночных тегов нету
Тег может содержать вложенные теги

Вот шаблоны тэгов из задания:

```
<tag>text1</tag>
<tag text2>text1</tag>
<tag
text2>text1</tag>
```

text1, text2 могут быть пустыми

Ввод такой:

```
<span>string1 <span>string2</span> string11</span>
```

Вывод должен быть таким:

```
<span>string1 <span>string2</span> string11</span>
<span>string2</span>
```

Какой регэксп для этого нужен?
Вот мой тестировочный код:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String testStr = "<span>string1 <span>string2</span> string11</span>";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\<(/?[^\\>]+)\\>)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(testStr);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(testStr.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Регэксп неправильный прибор для этого. Лучше использовать HTML парсер, например [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: И снова вспоминается [отличный ответ о HTML и Regex на английском SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2170192)

Comment: Я понимаю, что это неправильный выбор с практической точки зрения. (синтаксис в html не строгий и пр.).
Но задача стоит именно в том, чтобы написать свою реализацию.

Есть еще вариант сделать рекурсивно, но я не нагуглил ничего внятного на эту тему (в смысле самого алгоритма) :(

Comment: "Но задача стоит именно в том, чтобы написать свою реализацию" Ну-ну. Доя студента самое то, до кандидатской доберёшься :)

Comment: от чего такой коммент? Задача поставлена некорректно?

Comment: Вообще был бы благодарен за ссылку на рекурсивный нисходящий парсер (на сам алгоритм). Я выяснил что т к html файлы имеют древовидную структуру, то его можно будет применить.
Если я ошибаюсь, прошу указать где и в чем, и наставить меня на истинное направление :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать это можно. Производительность только будет ничтожна.
Падение производительности будет не сколько от рекурсии, а от того, что нужно найти совпадения еще и внутри уже сбалансированных тэгов.
Пример для поиска тэга span.

```
(?=(<span>(?:(?1)|<(?!\/span>)|[^<]*+)*+<\/span>))
```

Более общее выражение, но еще менее производительное:

```
(?=(<(span)>(?:(?1)|<(?!\/\2>)|[^<]*+)*+<\/\2>))
```

Текст:

```
<span>string1 <span>string2</span><span> string3 <span>string4</span> <span>string5</span> </span> string11</span>
```

Результат:

```
<span>string1 <span>string2</span><span> string3 <span>string4</span> <span>string5</span> </span> string11</span>
<span>string2</span>
<span> string3 <span>string4</span> <span>string5</span> </span>
<span>string4</span>
<span>string5</span>
```

https://regex101.com/r/dG0vP9/2