# Почему регулярное выражение выбрасывает исключение?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Вот задание:

Вывести на консоль все теги, которые соответствуют заданному тегу Каждый тег на новой строке, порядок должен соответствовать порядку следования в файле Количество пробелов, \n, \r не влияют на результат Файл не содержит тег CDATA, для всех открывающих тегов имеется отдельный закрывающий тег, одиночных тегов нету Тег может содержать вложенные теги

Вот шаблоны тэгов из задания:

```
<tag>text1</tag>
<tag text2>text1</tag>
<tag text2>text1</tag>
```

text1, text2 могут быть пустыми

Ввод такой:

```
<span>string1 <span>string2</span> string11</span>
```

Вывод должен быть таким:

```
<span>string1 <span>string2</span> string11</span>
<span>string2</span>
```

Какой регэксп для этого нужен? Вот мой тестировочный код:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String testStr = "<span>string1 <span>string2</span> string11</span>";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\<(/?[^\\>]+)\\>)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(testStr);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(testStr.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
        }

    }
}
```

И ответ к нему.

```
(?=((?:(?1)|<(?!/span>)|[^<]+)+</span>))
```

Но у меня не получается "прикрутить"

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=((?:(?1)|<(?!/span>)|[^<]+)+</span>))");
```

пишет вот такое:

> Exception in thread "main" `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException`: Dangling meta character '`?`' near index 0 `?=(<(span)>(?:(?1)|<(?!/\2>)|[^<]+)+</\2>)`

Подскажите как адаптировать регулярку под мою задачу?

Comment: Покажите код, который выбрасывает это исключение

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=((?:(?1)|<(?!/span>)|[^<]+)+</span>))");

Comment: @LEQADA: есть код.

Comment: дополнил вопрос.

Comment: могу гарантировать, что данная задача в общем виде при помощи регулярок не решается, т.к. возможны вложенные тэги. Поясни, что в твоём случае значит `(?1)`

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415734/Получить-тэги-html-с-их-содержимым-regexp-java.  Вот тут ответ есть он отмечен как правильный.

Comment: Он использует регулярки из php. Java выражения такого рода (обрати внимание на `(?1)`) пока не поддерживает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем регулярном выражении:

```
(?=((?:(?1)|<(?!/span>)|[^<]+)+</span>))
```

Определение группы захвата `(?1)` не является корректным с точки зрения синтаксиса регулярных выражений в JAVA, т.к. [рекурсивные паттеры из PHP PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) в ней не поддерживаются - ошибка выдаётся именно из-за этого

---

Вашу задачу необходимо решать с использованием HTML-парсера, например [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```java
String html = "<span>string1 <span>string2</span> string11</span>";
String tag = "span";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

document.select(tag).forEach((element) -> {
    System.out.println(element.outerHtml());
});
```

Этот код выводит:

> <span>string1 <span>string2</span> string11</span>
>   <span>string2</span>

Что вполне соответствует требуемому от правильного решения.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял. Другого ответа я и не нашел.