# Регулярные выражения, рекурсия

Tags: регулярные-выражения, рекурсия

Не так давно начал осваивать регулярные выражения.
Решил одну из задач решить с помощью рекурсии, но завис...
Итак, по условиям задачи необходимо найти парные теги и вывести все что между. 
Есть упрощенная строка тегов с тройной или n-вложенностью
qwe

необоходимо РВ которое будет ее искать и находить в тексте.
вот что получилось, но ищет все равно не полностью, последний закрывающий тег не находит

```
(<tag>)(?=(\w*<\/tag>)|(<tag>(?:\w*|(?3))<\/tag>)<\/tag>)
```

открывающий тег, смотрим вперед, если видим закрывающий тег - то все Ок, без вложений, дальше проверяем на вложенность тегов.

https://regex101.com/r/MQpwng/1

помогите доделать РВ, чтобы работала рекурсия полностью по закрывающиему тегу.

Comment: Если php, то есть поддержка рекурсии http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.recursive.php

Comment: java, если есть интересный мануал об который мозг в конец не закоротит, то киньте в меня ссылкой. Пока что не нашел дельного ничего

Comment: Тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/415801/186083 решение посмотрите.

Comment: Да, похоже решение к моей задаче. Тогда вопрос остаеться, где ошибка в моем РВ

Comment: Вы запутались при его написании, отсюда неправильная работа. Вы дублируете одну глубину вхождения и это ещё больше запутывает. Нельзя сказать, что «вот здесь ошибка, поэтому оно не работает» - оно просто работает не так как хочется.

Comment: `(?3)` не будет работать в регулярном выражении Java.

Comment: В Java рекурся в РВ не работает ?

Comment: Нет, вам понадибится другая библиотека. [Такая, например](https://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex).